# Do we need [sidebar]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sidebar) tag is currently described as follows:

> The sidebar tag is to be used for issues relating to displaying or rendering information to the side of an application.

It's used along with countless tags, such as [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), [windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) et al. Currently it's very broad and can mean countless different technologies and things in different contexts.

I don't think this is a tag that adds much to any question, in fact, most questions I scrolled through on a quick inspection seemed to rather fall on the lower quality side of things.

Do we need this tag?

Comment: It is a pretty decent contextual tag.  Not unlike [performance], [debugging], [exception], [events], [memory].  Other tags on the question disambiguate.

Comment: For a second I thought this said `sidecar` and I was like, yes we need a [sidecar](http://www.alzinfo.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/sidecar.jpg).